# WCF: How to serialize DataTable using DataContractSerializer?

Tags: wcf, serialization

I have some wcf service:

```
[ServiceContract(SessionMode = SessionMode.Allowed)]
public interface IMyService
{
   [OperationContract]
   [TransactionFlow(TransactionFlowOption.Allowed)]
   FooResult GetFoo([NotNull] FooRequest request);
}

[DataContract(Name = "FooRequest", Namespace = "...")]
public class FooRequest
{
    [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
    [NotNull]
    public DateTime From { get; set; }
}
```

By this service svcutil generates types that serialize by DataContractSerializer. Now I add method that returns DataTable:

```
[OperationContract]
[TransactionFlow(TransactionFlowOption.Allowed)]
[FaultContract(typeof(IikoNetServiceFault))]
System.Data.DataTable GetDataTable();
```

Now svcutils generate types that serialize all the types by XmlSerializer. But I need either all types (including DataTable) are serialized by DataContractSerializer or only DataTable is serialized by XmlSerializer, but other types are serialized by DataContractSerializer.

Comment: Usually it is not a good idea to send DataTable as an output of a service, too much extra data. Would be better to create some data transfer objects. This would most probably solve the serialization problems also.

Comment: You cannot have two serialization engines for the same service. SOA does not know anything about DataTable. Service contranct is language independent, what will PHP or python do with your DataTable? :) Better use data transfer objects as ElDog said.

Comment: Even though I completely agree with @ElDog that POCOs should generally be preferred in service contracts, I have to point out the WCF is not *only* about interoperable services, but is a general purpose technology for building distributed systems. If the clients are known to be based on .NET, I don't see a problem with using .NET specific types in the service contract, as long as [they can be serialized](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347876.aspx).

Comment: I read this link, but I realy need either all types (including DataTable) are serialized by DataContractSerializer or only DataTable is serialized by XmlSerializer, but other types are serialized by DataContractSerializer.

Comment: Why cant you mark your service with the [XmlSerializerFormat] Attribute and hence all the data types would use XmlSerializer

Comment: Also according to this article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731923.aspx DataTable is supported by DataContractSerializer

Comment: I cannot mark my service as XmlSerializerFormat because have some limitation I cannot make other types xmlserializable.

Answer (score -1):

The **svcutil** utility generates client-side code that uses the [XmlSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx) for types that can't be handled by the [DataContractSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer.aspx), which is otherwise the default choice.

However, you can force **svcutil** to use one serializer over the other with the `/serializer` switch:

```
svcutil /serializer:DataContractSerializer http://server/myservice.svc
```

**Alternatively**, you could apply the [XmlSerializerFormatAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.xmlserializerformatattribute.aspx) on the `GetDataTable` service operation *only*, to make it use the [XmlSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx) while the rest of the contract will continue to use the [DataContractSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer.aspx):

```
[ServiceContract]
[DataContractFormat]
public interface IMyService
{
   [OperationContract]
   FooResult GetFoo(FooRequest request);

   [OperationContract]
   [XmlSerializerFormat]
   DataTable GetDataTable();
}
```

Comment: @user876743 I updated my answer with an alternative solution.

Comment: Thats because DataContractSerializer will always fall back to use XmlSerializer under specific conditions, which you can read about here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733112.aspx

Comment: Enrico, but what about other types? Will the be serialized using XmlSerializer?

Comment: @user876743 No, only the service operation decorated with the `XmlSerializerFormat` attribute will use the `XmlSerializer`. The others will use the `DataContractSerializer`.